# domPDF no imprime operador lógico menor que ( < )

Tags: php

Buenas tardes, quisiera saber por qué la librería dompdf de php no imprime el operador lógico menor que. Este dato está alojado en una columna de mi BD. Lo único que hago es imprimirlo y no aparece. Sin embargo el operador mayor que, si lo acepta.
¿Alguna idea del por qué?

EL tipo de dato en la BD es `Varchar`.
Y la consulta php es un simple `echo` de esa columna.

Comment: Muestra el codigo, la consulta que haces para obtener el valor y como esta guardado en el campo

Comment: Seguramente porque lo interepreta como una apertura de etiqueta. Intenta reemplazarlo con `&lt;` o `&#60;`

Comment: Muchas gracias :') Era eso

Comment: Mira mi ejemplo, la manera correcta de usar `load_html/loadHtml` con texto que puede contener caracteres especiales HTML es con la función PHP `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Hola @Yami, ¿podrías revisar las respuestas, votar las que te hayan ayudado y marcar como solución aquella que te solucione el problema? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces uso del método [`load_html/loadHtml`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#loadhtml) de dompdf debes convertir los caracteres especiales de HTML en entidades HTML con [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html(htmlspecialchars('Sabemos que 5 < 10, ¿verdad? <SÍ>'));

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('document.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

tal vez no puedas imprimir caracteres especiales porque necesitas usar el codigo html de cada caracter para reemplazar todos los caracteres especiales te sugiero usar algo como esto:

```
function caracteresHTML($str){
    $c = array("<", ">", "ñ", "á"); //caracteres a reemplazar
    $h = array("&lt;", "&gt;", "&ntilde;", "&aacute;"); //valores a imprimir
    return str_replace($c, $h, $str);
}

$myVar=caracteresHTML($myVar);
```

e imprimir la variable myVar funcionaría